# Why cypher query faster in neo4j admin panel than in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

Here is my query:

```
MATCH (me:User{username: 'username'})-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post|post_in_gr|post_in_page]->(posts1:Post) WHERE posts1.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(posts1) return posts1 as posts
      UNION
      MATCH (me:User{username: 'username'})-[{subscribe: '1'}]-()-[:post_in_gr]-(posts3:Post)-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-(User{status:'active'}) WHERE posts3.access IN ['everybody', 'friend'] AND posts3.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(posts3) RETURN posts3 as posts
      UNION
      MATCH (me:User{username: 'username'})-[{subscribe: '1'}]-()-[:post_in_page]-(posts4:Post)-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-({status:'active'}) WHERE posts4.access IN ['everybody', 'friend'] AND posts4.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(posts4) RETURN posts4 as posts
      UNION
      MATCH (me:User{username: 'username'})-[:user_author_page]-()-[:post_in_page]-(posts5:Post)-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-({status:'active'}) WHERE posts5.access IN ['everybody', 'friend'] AND posts5.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(posts5) RETURN posts5 as posts
      UNION
      MATCH (me:User{username: 'username'})-[{subscribe: '1'}]-({status:'active'})-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-(posts6:Post{system_type: 'page'}) WHERE posts6.access IN ['everybody', 'friend'] AND posts6.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(posts6) RETURN posts6 as posts
      UNION
      MATCH (me:User{username: 'username'})-[{subscribe: '1'}]-({status:'active'})-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-(posts7:Post)  WHERE posts7.access IN ['everybody', 'friend'] AND NOT (posts7)-[:post_in_gr]-() AND NOT (posts7)-[:post_in_page]-() AND posts7.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(posts7) RETURN posts7 as posts
      UNION 
      MATCH (me:User{username: 'username'})-[:user_create_com]-()-[:com_in_post]-(posts8:Post) WHERE  posts8.access IN ['everybody', 'friend'] AND posts8.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(posts8) RETURN posts8 as posts
      UNION
      MATCH (me:User{username: 'username'})-[:user_can_see_post|user_posted_post]-(posts9:Post) WHERE posts9.access = 'custom' AND posts9.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(posts9) RETURN posts9 as posts").to_a
```

This query takes about 1300 ms in admin panel, but the same query in rails app takes more than 4000 ms.

In rails app i use Neo4j::Session.query to make this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same similar issue using Python compared to Java.  Unfortunately, I can't speak to the Rails integration specifically, but, I can offer some thoughts on performance:

1) Check the profile of the query.   Remember, you're actually executing 8 unique queries
2) Look at the queries with multiple relationships, and un-labeled nodes

for example:

MATCH (me:User{username: 'username'})-[:user_author_page]-()-[:post_in_page]-(posts5:Post)-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-({status:'active'}) WHERE posts5.access IN ['everybody', 'friend'] AND posts5.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(posts5) RETURN posts5 as posts

3) Try the same query in another language, using another driver.  Perhaps its the Ruby driver that stinks?  The python one took 30-40x the time to translate nodes to native python objects, compared to Java

chris.

https://fauie.com

Comment: You are right. Here is what i found out. I have added to each query LIMIT statement and it works much faster, about 1 second.
So now i want to, make this 8 queries, then, order them by updated_at field and take only first 10 of them. How can i do it?

Comment: How many results are you talking about?   Let's say you want 10 results in your final final final result set.   If you set the limit to 10 for each of these 8, you'll end up with 80 'temporary final' results.      If it were me, first choice would be to sort and get the latest 10 in your ruby code.      Would you mind marking my answer as accepted?